# Flex - error 1046 - some .as files don't get importet

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I received a Flex project and when trying to compile it i get a few 1046 errors that say the Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant MyClass

however - the respective files are listed on the top of the file in an import clause like this:

```
import com.folder1.folder2.folder3.MyClass;
```

and if i check the folder structure, MyClass.as is there.

however, if i type this same line (import com.folder1.folder2.folder3.MyClass;) and check at each . what the autocompletion suggests, I see only a subset of the as classes that are actually there on the harddisk.

What determines which classes and folders are suggested by the autocompletion function? I don't get any compile error on the corresponding import statements that import MyClass

//edit:

screenshot 1 shows the file in which the error occurs that tries to import the class in question (Updater)

```
http://neo.cycovery.com/flex_problem.gif
```

screenshot 2 shows the file Updater.as

```
http://neo.cycovery.com/flex_problem2.gif
```

the censored part of the path matches in both cases (folder structure and package statement in Updater.as)

screenshot 3 shows where the error actually happens:

```
http://neo.cycovery.com/flex_problem3.gif
```

interestingly, the variable declaration

```
private var _updater:Updater = new Updater();
```

further up in the file does not give an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is set up wrong. Its obvious your application can not find the classes.
Move your **"com"** folder and all of the contents into your **"src"** folder.
Or perhaps include the files in your source path? 
right click on the project name->properties->flex Build Path->add folder

Answer (score 0):

the import is based on the 'package' declaration within the file itself (at the top of the file).  If the file's package declaration does not match the actual folder structure, you will get problems.

Comment: thank you. I checked this and the package declaration matches the folder structure. see the screenshots i added to my original post

Comment: Try to do a 'clean' on your project.

Comment: Your events folder seems to be empty on the first picture.

Comment: nono it's not empty. just on the first screenshot somehow all the little triangles disappeared

Comment: 'clean' doesn't seem to do anything. the problems persist

Comment: i have to add: further up in the file there is a line `private var _updater:Updater = new Updater();` which does not give any error

Comment: could it be some kind of nameconflict? I read in this article http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=updating_apps_1.html that there is already a class called "Updater" in flash.desktop - though - if i type import flash.desktop. the autocomplete doesn't show me a Updater class

Answer (score 0):

Check the classes you can't see in the autocompletion list. Maybe those classes' package name doesn't match the actual structure.

Rob

Comment: thank you. I just checked this and the names seem to match. I added screenshots to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Check your actionscript source paths. Any chance that the folders you are seeing (events and objects) are in there explicitly, and the others are not? Normally, you have all your source inside a folder like src that is in the source path, so that the compiler can find anything anywhere inside it. But you can just as easily make your source paths too specific and just see a few things...